# Why doesn't this snippet add 1?

Tags: python

```
nb = 1 # nb = 1
while nb < 10: # while nb is inferior do this
    print(nb," * 7 = ",nb * 7) # print: 1 * 7 = 7
nb1 += 1 # add 1 to nb
```

my problem is that it doesn't add 1 to `nb` and instead infinite loops!

I am not looking for solution, just need someone to explain it to me. Because I know I could use this code:

```
nb = 7 
i = 0 
while i < 10:
    print(i + 1, "*", nb, "=", (i + 1) * nb)
    i += 1
```

Comment: Do you see the difference in indentation?

Comment: in python, your use of indentation is important.

Answer (score 5):

Python uses indents for their blocks. Your initial program does not include the `nb1 += 1 # add 1 to nb` in the while block because it is not indented to the same level as the `print` statement. Also, you are assigning the `+= 1` to a different variable `nb1`. Based on the comment, I assume you want to assign it to the previously created variable `nb`. What you want is like so:

```
nb = 1 #nb = 1
while nb < 10: # while nb is inferior do this
    print(nb," * 7 = ",nb * 7) # print: 1 * 7 = 7
    nb += 1 # add 1 to nb
```

Comment: This still won't work because `nb1` is a different variable from `nb`.

Comment: You're right, I didn't notice that piece. I'll add that to the answer.